# Approach to prove vector spaces and subspaces of vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $(E,+,.)$ be a $K$-vector space and $F$ a subspace of $E$, it follows that both meet certain requirements to be what they are.

My question : what is your approach in proving both to be what they are? With which condition do you start first? $0_E \in F$ for a subspace as a first step perhaps? Or do you look for certain characteristics?
Generally are there indications that one rule won't be met and thus one would avoid wasting time by going through each?

Comment: It really depends on the problem you're looking at. If you are asked to prove that E *is* a subspace of F then it doesn't matter much where you start, since all of them will turn out to be true. So in this case I would start with the "easiest" and work your way up. If you think that one of them may fail, then try to build some intuition about why F is *not* a subspace and work to find the failing condition from this intuition.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of vector spaces, the first thing that I would check is whether it is closed for addition. In the case of fields, the first things that I would check is whether the multiplication is commutative and whether each non-zero element has an inverse.